# convert date from variable array to get day in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, iterator

i have an array

```
let arr = [
  "2018-10-10",
"2018-10-11",
"2018-10-12"
]
```

i have read how to convert the date such as this

```
let date = new Date(dateSTRING);
    let days = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tues', 'Wed', 'Thurs', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
    let name = days[date.getDay()];
```

but, how to convert that array to `getDay()`?
should we use Iterators?

and the result I want is like this :

`today is Wed`

`today is Thurs`

`today is fri`

Comment: One loop would do it.

Comment: can you give me example?? @PM77-1

Comment: I would highly suggest that you edit your question following the guidelines of [this StackOverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.map` to iterate over the values of your array:

```js
let arr = [
  "2018-10-10",
"2018-10-11",
"2018-10-12"
];
let days = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tues', 'Wed', 'Thurs', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
let today = arr.map(date => 'today is ' + days[new Date(date).getDay()]);
console.log(today);
```

In the map function, `new Date(date)` creates a `Date` object from the date string in the array; calling the `.getDay()` method then returns a value from 0-6 dependent on what day of the week it is and finally we use that as an index into the `days` array to get a text version of that value.

Comment: i was be  able to get the result like  that by ForEach, but, how to return that to an variable then??

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? You can just assign the output of `arr.map` to a variable (see my edit).

Comment: i got it , thx, 
but  can i know what is method called = `days[new Date(date).getDay()]` ??

i meant this let name = days[date.getDay()];
because i found that on another question on stackoverflow

Comment: @iLnx did this answer your question? If not, can you provide more info to help answer it?